# Maven. Complete a java-code during building

Tags: java, maven

I have a JSON-file filled with an initial data. Sometimes I need to update it and I have a special java-class with main method which is responsible for updating. 
Is there any way to run this method during building of jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main" [-Dexec.args="argument1"] ...
```

Example pom:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            ...
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>argument1</argument>
            ...
          </arguments>
          <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
              <key>myproperty</key>
              <value>myvalue</value>
            </systemProperty>
            ...
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```